# Cannot read property 'components' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular

People,

I'm trying to access a function that is present in a JavaScript file inside my Angular project and I'm getting error of could not find the method, but that same function works in an HTML, CSS and JavaScript project.

In the Angular project the error message it displays is as follows

[image]

Can not read property 'components' of undefined

ncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'init' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.  (Payments: 93) ...

My HTML component is as follows

```
<!-- JS Plugins Init. -->
<script >
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // initialization of rating
    $.HSCore.components.HSRating.init($('.js-rating'), {
      spacing: 4
    });

    // initialization of carousel
    $.HSCore.components.HSCarousel.init('.js-carousel');
  });
</script>
```

My JavaScript file

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.HSCore.components.HSCarousel = {
        /**
         *
         *
         * @var Object _baseConfig
         */
        _baseConfig: {
            autoplay: false,
            infinite: true
        },

        /**
         *
         *
         * @var jQuery pageCollection
         */
        pageCollection: $(),

        /**
         * Initialization of Carousel wrapper.
         *
         * @param String selector (optional)
         * @param Object config (optional)
         *
         * @return jQuery pageCollection - collection of initialized items.
         */
        init: function(selector, config) {...
```

Comment: `$.HSCore` is probably undefined. Check this in your debugger.

Comment: On a more general note, you're not really supposed to use jQuery with Angular - Angular is supposed to do everything that jQuery does. If you *really* want to use it though, make sure you install and use it [as an npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) and not through a script tag.

Comment: how is angular made available to your code? do you have angular.element available in code?

Comment: @NinoFiliu 
able to perform my interaction using only the bootstrap. Thanks in advance for your attention.

How can I rate your answer here in the forum?